# pandas.set_option to give detail of Dataframe rather than returning frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` called `result`.

In the tutorial I'm watching Wes McKinney is getting the following return data when he executes a cell with just the name of the df in it - when I execute a cell with `result` in it I get the whole frame being returned.

Is there a pandas set_option I can use to swap between return info?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a `display.large_repr` option for that:

```
In [95]: pd.set_option('large_repr', 'info')

In [96]: df
Out[96]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1000000 entries, 0 to 999999
Data columns (total 3 columns):
a    1000000 non-null int32
b    1000000 non-null int32
c    1000000 non-null int32
dtypes: int32(3)
memory usage: 11.4 MB
```

from [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html):

> **display.large_repr** : ‘truncate’/’info’
>
> For DataFrames exceeding
>   max_rows/max_cols, the repr (and HTML repr) can show a truncated table
>   (the default from 0.13), or switch to the view from df.info() (the
>   behaviour in earlier versions of pandas).
>
> [default: truncate]
>   [currently: truncate]

PS You may also want to read about [frequently used pandas options](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#frequently-used-options)

**but IMO it would be much more convenient and more conscious to use [.info()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.info.html) function:**

```
result.info()
```

demo:

```
In [92]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1000000 entries, 0 to 999999
Data columns (total 3 columns):
a    1000000 non-null int32
b    1000000 non-null int32
c    1000000 non-null int32
dtypes: int32(3)
memory usage: 11.4 MB

In [93]: df.head()
Out[93]:
   a  b  c
0  1  0  1
1  6  1  9
2  5  2  3
3  6  4  3
4  8  9  2
```

Comment: Thanks - Wes's tutorial is from 2012 so this may well be the new (and only) way to get this info. Is there also a setting that you know of?

Comment: Thanks - I actually really like the idea of the setting: it is quite a defensive strategy so that the notebook isn't trying to render too much data. If Wes was using it in his tutorial then maybe a good idea: although the tutorial is from a few years ago.

Answer (score 1):

`df.info(verbose=None, buf=None, max_cols=None, memory_usage=None, null_counts=None)` method will give you what you want. By default, information about the number of values and the size of the dataframe will be displayed. The documentation is [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.info.html).  The verbose setting might be particularly useful for larger datasets as it shows full output including number of notnull values.

Default:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 100 entries, 0 to 99
Columns: 10 entries, 0 to 9
dtypes: float64(10)
memory usage: 7.9 KB
```

With verbose = True:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 100 entries, 0 to 99
Data columns (total 10 columns):
0    100 non-null float64
1    100 non-null float64
2    100 non-null float64
3    100 non-null float64
4    100 non-null float64
5    100 non-null float64
6    100 non-null float64
7    100 non-null float64
8    100 non-null float64
9    100 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(10)
memory usage: 7.9 KB
```

Comment: (upped) thanks - interesting to see the use of the  verbose argument of the info method.